# How to check if the sum of all the previous elements in the array are greater than the next element in the array?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

For example I was given an array and I have to check whether all the sum of all the previous elements in the array are greater than the next element.

for instance i have given (1,2,3) now 1+2 is not greater than 3 so false in this case. again (1,1,1) given. Now 1+1 is strictly greater than 1.

```
for x in range(1,len(i)):
           if(sum(i[0:x])>sum(i[x:])):
            #   print(str(i[:x])+str(i[x:]))
               Ways+=1
```

Comment: Please consider sharing your code segment, with error messages or what you have tried as an attempt for the solution.

Comment: @ChintanRajvir I have added what Im trying

Comment: Considering your question segment, the IF statement should be something like: `if(sum(i[:x])>i[x]:`. Your approach is making use of brute-force technique. You can optimize it by computing a prefix sum array.

Answer (score -1):

If by the "next element", I assume you mean the *last* element, meaning you have to find if the sum of all of the values, up until the last element, are greater than the last element. Correct me if I'm wrong.

If this is the case, then simply loop through the array until the last element, and add the values of the current loop to another variable, then return if that variable is greater than the last element or not.

For example:

```js
n.onkeyup = n.onkeypress = n.onkeydown = n.onfocus = n.onchange = n.onblur = () => {
  var allOtherElementsSum = 0,
      myArray = n.value.split(" ").map(x => x.trim()).filter(x=>x)
  myArray.forEach((x, i, a) => (i < a.length - 1) && (allOtherElementsSum += parseInt(x)))
  var isGreater = myArray[myArray.length-1] <= allOtherElementsSum
  out.innerHTML = "array: " + myArray + ", sum: " + allOtherElementsSum + ", and last element: "+ myArray[myArray.length-1] + ", is sum greater or not than last element: " + isGreater
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="type a bunch of numbers separated by spaces" id=n><div id=out></div>
```

Comment: It's now last element. I was talking about every time you came across an element n then consider all the previous n-1 elements.

Comment: @classydraught what does that mean consider all of the previous n-1 elements? what is your return value? a single number? an array? can u give an example?